# Difference between `cherrypy.InternalRedirect` vs. `cherrypy.HTTPRedirect`?

Tags: cherrypy

I have studied the code as follow in Cherrypy web development,

```
if returnpage != '':
   raise cherrypy.InternalRedirect(returnpage)
else:
   raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/hqc")
```

Google doesn't help much in this case after I did some research.
I've checked from cherrypy's `__doc__`, but the documentation there is very terse.

```
>>>print(cherrypy.InternalRedirect.__doc__)
Exception raised to switch to the handler for a different URL.

    This exception will redirect processing to another path within the site
    (without informing the client). Provide the new path as an argument when
    raising the exception. Provide any params in the querystring for the new URL.

>>> print(cherrypy.HTTPRedirect.__doc__)
Exception raised when the request should be redirected.

    This exception will force a HTTP redirect to the URL or URL's you give it.
    The new URL must be passed as the first argument to the Exception,
    e.g., HTTPRedirect(newUrl). Multiple URLs are allowed in a list.
    If a URL is absolute, it will be used as-is. If it is relative, it is
    assumed to be relative to the current cherrypy.request.path_info.

    If one of the provided URL is a unicode object, it will be encoded
    using the default encoding or the one passed in parameter.

    There are multiple types of redirect, from which you can select via the
    ``status`` argument. If you do not provide a ``status`` arg, it defaults to
    303 (or 302 if responding with HTTP/1.0).

    Examples::

        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("")
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/abs/path", 307)
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(["path1", "path2?a=1&b=2"], 301)

    See :ref:`redirectingpost` for additional caveats.
```

My questions are:
- Why bother with redirect when you can simply invoke another handler?
- What are some practical senarios for the two redirect exception respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InternalRedirect` is only handled in the server side, this means that the client would not be aware of that redirection, because in terms of the HTTP protocol that is mediating the session between the client and the server, nothing changed. By server side I mean ONLY CherryPy will be *aware* of the rediction, if you have some intermediate server (like an nginx reverse proxy) it would not see anything different.

For example if the client visited a url `/page_one` and then you used `raise InternalRedirect('/page_two')`, the client (browser) will receive the content from the `/page_two` handler in the `/page_one` url. If you raised a regular `HTTPRedirect` the server would end the first request with an HTTP status code of `303` (or any other status that you passed to the exception) and a `Location` header to `/page_two`. Then is the client who will initiate another request to `/page_two`, basically everybody will be *aware* of the redirection ([more info about HTTP redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)). Most of the time this is the better alternative.

Additionally you could detect if the request came from a previous `InternalRedirect` by verifying the `cherrypy.request.prev` property. It will have the previous `cherrypy.request` object as its value or `None`.

For the sake of a possible (maybe not the best example) use of an `InternalRedirect`, checkout this production/beta example page, in addition I added a tool to prohibit the client to reach to handlers directly.

The client will see a different content in the same page `/`. Note that the access log that CherryPy generates will log the url of the handler that end up handling the request, in this case you will see `/_beta` or `/_production`.

```python
import random
import cherrypy


@cherrypy.tools.register('before_handler')
def private_handler():
    """End the request with HTTP 404 not found if the client
    tries to reach the handler directly instead of being
    internally redirected from other handler.
    """
    if cherrypy.request.prev is None:
        raise cherrypy.NotFound()


class MainApp:

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        # 50/50 change of receiving production or the new SHINY beta page
        use_beta = random.randint(0, 1)
        if use_beta:
            raise cherrypy.InternalRedirect('/_beta')
        else:
            raise cherrypy.InternalRedirect('/_production')

    @cherrypy.tools.private_handler()
    @cherrypy.expose
    def _production(self):
        return (
            "<html>"
            "<h2>{}</h2>"
            "</html>"
        ).format(
            "Welcome to our awesome site!"
        )

    @cherrypy.tools.private_handler()
    @cherrypy.expose
    def _beta(self):
        return (
            "<html>"
            '<h1 style="color: blue">{}</h1>'
            "<p>{}</p>"
            "</html>"
        ).format(
            "Welcome to our awesome site!",
            "Here is our new beta content..."
        )


cherrypy.quickstart(MainApp())
```

Comment: Should I be able to view a address bar change after `HTTPRedirect`? Mine doesn't seem to change anything. I had to open developer's tool to view Network requests and responses to find out the redirected `Location`. Is this normal?

Comment: Actually not being able to view anything changed in address bar is why I was suspicious that the two work the same.

Comment: No this is not normal... you _should_ see a different address. Gave it a try in firefox and chrome and it does update the address.

Comment: The documentation says you can feed a list of addresses to HTTPRedirect. I can't think of a scenario where you need more than one target. Could you give some clue here?

Comment: I think that this is a case on which a standard is followed, but the practice has evolved differently. For example 300 "Multiple Choices" reads: "... If the server has a preferred choice, the server SHOULD generate a Location header field containing a preferred choice's URI reference. The user agent MAY use the Location field value for automatic redirection." https://httpstatuses.com/300, the only difference when you pass a list of urls, is that those URLS will be return as html links in the body of the response. For example It seem that google chrome does not execute the automatic redirect.

Comment: In 2020 I can't think of a good use of it, but that particular part of cherrypy seems to be written looking at the HTTP/1.1 protocol specification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212237/discussion-between-jinghui-niu-and-cyraxjoe).

Comment: Regarding `InternalRedirect`, if it's only for Cherrypy, then why not simply invoke the handler method itself? `if use_beta:
            return self.beta()
        else:
            return self.production` Why bother `redirecting` at all?

Comment: If you redirect using the internal redirect, you trigger the hooks (tool connection points) and also, this is a trivial example, you could have an application composed from classes from different namespaces, having independent modules and just _abstractly_ redirect to wherever page handler is handling that path will lead to a simpler implementation.